# Render a HTML page using MySQL (Dynamic lines)

Tags: php, html, mysql

I am wondering how I would render a HTML page with MySQL.
I want to render a page that has different lines, for different rows in the table.

The table is:
[image]

I want the web page to render like this:

[image]

Obviously, if there are less rows I don't want as many rows to display, and same if there are more.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Purely because it's late at night here's some free code.

Please notice two things.
1. I'm using mysqli not mysql.
2. I wrote this from memory, I researched on the web how to write this. I have no degree, no professional job as a programmer but I all found this out by myself by researching and browsing SO. Please next time research and try out different things for yourself.

```
<?php

$host = 'localhost';
$password = '';
$user = '';
$database = '';

// Link for the connection to MySQL
$link = mysqli_connect($host,$user,$pass);

// If statement to check if the link has been succesful if not, give error. If it is succesful select database.
if(!$link)
{
    if (mysqli_connect_errno()) 
    {
        echo "Connection unsuccessful<br/>";
        printf("Connect failed: %s\n", mysqli_connect_error());
        exit();
    }
}else
{
    mysqli_select_db($link, $database);
}

$query = "SELECT * FROM [table]";
$result = mysqli_query($link, $query);
echo '<table>';
while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result))
{
    echo '<tr>';
        echo '<td>'. $row['CSTEAMID'] .'</td>'
        echo '<td>'. $row['OSTEAMID'] .'</td>'
        echo '<td>'. $row['TIMEJOINED'] .'</td>'
    echo '</tr>';
}
echo '</table>';
?>
```

Comment: In hindsight I now see I didn't add in the ID of the rows. But you can figure it out.

Comment: `echo "Connection unsuccesful</br>';` should be `echo "Connection unsuccessful<br/>";`

Comment: @Sean and why is that?

Comment: (1) you start the echo with a double quote `echo "...` but end it with a single quote `';` so you have a php syntax error (if you look at the code hinting/coloring that SO does, you would see there is a syntax error), (2) minor spelling issue of `unsuccessful`, and (3) `</br>` is invalid html syntax, as it should be `<br>` or `<br/>`.

Comment: @Sean Ah I see now, I was looking at the `/` you moved around in the BR tag.

Comment: @Sean Edited the things you pointed out Sean, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Do you have any code already?

Pseudo code for what you want:

- Write html for a standard page
- In the body somewhere, use PHP (or other scripting language) to connect to your mysql db and retrieve the needed data.
- Output with the PHP in an HTML tabular format